# How to edit home.jsp

Tags: customer-community

We have created Site/Community for Guest Users. These Guest Users have been assigned a Custom Profile with limited access. We have written a URL Rewritter class which after logging gets the Guest User to the desired URL.

After logging to Community, the User is redirected to the default Communities Landing Page - '/home/home.jsp page'. I need to edit this page. Where can I find this page on Salesforce

Answer (score 0):

Go to  the custom profile you created and then  look for standard object layout. There you will see the Home Page Layout and view the assignment.